# Why does collections.find({}) takes over 9 secs for 250 objects (MongoMapper)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I am running the following query and it is take on average 9 seconds to return the results. There are no filters on it, so I am not sure an index would help. Why is this running so slowly? There are only 250 objects in there, and only 4 fields (all text).

```
Country.collection.find({},:fields => ['country_name', 'country_code']).to_json

"cursor":"BasicCursor",
"nscanned":247,
"nscannedObjects":247,
"n":247,
"millis":0,
"nYields":0,
"nChunkSkips":0,
"isMultiKey":false,
"indexOnly":false,
"indexBounds":{},
"allPlans":[{"cursor":"BasicCursor","indexBounds":{}}]
```

The cpu, memory and disk on the machine do not even notice the query run. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try running the same query in mongo shell?

Comment: no, to honest I haven't lot of experience in the mongo shell, what syntax changes would I need to make so that it treated it as the same query?

Comment: something like: `db.countries.find({}, {'country_name' : 1, 'country_code' : 1})`

Comment: Okay, in mongo shell running the query responses with the first 20 records instantly with a 'has more' tag. If I run explain(), I get this:
`"cursor":"BasicCursor", 
"nscanned":247,
"nscannedObjects": 247,
"n":247,
"millis":0,
"nYields":0,
"nchunkSkips":0,
"isMultikey":false,
"indexOnly":false,
"indexBounds":{}`

Comment: So what is going wrong within mongomapper that is causing such a delay?

Comment: I'm not a rubyist but i'd try using profiler.

Comment: Your explain() looks fine.  I would check for a problem in the application or network layer if your database server otherwise seems fine for cpu, memory, and disk; I assume "do not notice the query" means you have plenty of free resource on all fronts.  Is MongoDB running on the same machine as your application, or are you connecting over a network?  If you are using a hostname in your application's mongodb connect string, you should also try with an IP address in case there is a delay in name resolution.

Comment: FYI, for some general stats on MongoDB activity you can use the included [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/) command line tool.  Output of mongostat includes a sampling of information such as database operations, memory usage, I/O, and network traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create indexes on the 'country_name' fiels using :

```
db.countries.ensureIndex({country_name:1});
```

That will speed your query enormously
You can learn more about indexes [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes)

PS-
you can type 'it' to display more when you see the 'has more' phrase, or you can display all the result without the 'has more' by using:

```
db.countries.find({}, {'country_name' : 1, 'country_code' : 1}).forEach(printjson)
```

and you can always set the profiler by using:

```
>use databaseName;
> db.setProfilingLevel(2); // 2 tell the profiler to catch everything happened inside the DB
```

You can learn more about profiler [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)

and you can display the data inside the profiler using

```
> db.system.profile.find()
```

This method will give you more info about your database and what's  going on inside.

Comment: Thank you, running db.countries.find({}, {'country_name' : 1, 'country_code' : 1}).forEach(printjson) in the shell executes and returns all the results within milliseconds, as I would expect mongo to. I'm going to install a profiler onto my ruby stack is see what is causing a query which should execute in milliseconds execute in seconds.

Comment: Let me know if creating the index speed up your query, it's a great feature within mongodb.

Comment: sadly not, but it turns out it was not mongo, but the ruby driver and to_json that was slowing things down. I ended up caching the json result it works really well. Now the whole ajax call completes end to end within 70ms

Comment: Great to hear that everything works great for you now! Post more if you have more questions!